# how to auto complete cities list based on entered state name in PHP MySQL and JQuery

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I am able to auto fill(complete) states and cities textboxes independently using below mentioned script.

But I want to do following.

- First I enter state name in state textbox and select any state from suggested states list.
- There after I enter city name in city textbox but at that time suggested cities list should be filtered according to selected state.
- For Example: First I enter/select 'New York' in state textbox, after that when I enter city name in city textbox then I should get suggest cities list only for 'New York' state.

Please let me know what changes I need to do in script to get desired result.

NOTE: statepkid field is available in tr_cities table for relation.

index.php

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script>
    $(function() {
        $( "#statename" ).autocomplete({
          source: 'search.php'
        });
    });
    $(function() {
        $( "#cityname" ).autocomplete({
          source: 'c_search.php'
        });
    });
</script>

<div class="ui-widget">
    <label for="statename">State: </label>
    <input id="statename">

    <label for="cityname">City: </label>
    <input id="cityname">
</div>
```

search.php (for states)

```
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = 'password';
$dbName = '10000dbname';
$db = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);
$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tr_states WHERE statename LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY statename ASC");
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row['statename'];
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

c_search.php (for cities)

```
$dbHost = 'localhost';
$dbUsername = 'root';
$dbPassword = 'password';
$dbName = '10000dbname';
$db = new mysqli($dbHost,$dbUsername,$dbPassword,$dbName);
$searchTerm = $_GET['term'];
$query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tr_cities WHERE city LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY city ASC");
while ($row = $query->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[] = $row['city'];
}
echo json_encode($data);
```

Comment: try to get state value and pass it in `source: `c_search.php?state={value}`. and apply filter in your query

Comment: So you want 'cascading' or 'dependent' drop downs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JS

```
source: 'c_search.php?state=' + $('#statename').val()
```

and in php file

I am assuming that the column name is `state_id` in you city table.

```
if(isset($_GET['state'])){
$stateid = $_GET['state'];
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tr_cities WHERE city LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' AND state_id = ".$stateid."  ORDER BY city ASC");
}else{
    $query = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tr_cities WHERE city LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' ORDER BY city ASC");
}
```

Comment: initially I could not realize one syntax error (one ) missing) in if condition and one spelling error in sql query (ANS -> AND) and thus it was not working but now it is working fine. Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @KAhir : Thanks for notifying the errors. and Glad to know it works.

Comment: There is small issue with script. It gives same cities suggested list no what I select New York or New Jersey as state. Can you please help into this issue?

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle

Comment: How can I add PHP code into jsfiddle? Sorry but I am not much familiar with it.

Comment: use it as external file

Comment: my site is at local server right now. It's not hosted on hosting server so can't be accessible on internet. Is there other way for it? Please let me know.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104998/discussion-between-urfusion-and-k-ahir).

Comment: Ty... If I use this query... 

$query = $db_cities->query("SELECT * FROM tr_cities WHERE city LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' AND statename='New Jersey' ORDER BY city ASC"); 

... it is working fine for all states and cities.... but If I use below query... then it is giving incorrect results.... 

$query = $db_cities->query("SELECT * FROM tr_cities WHERE city LIKE '%".$searchTerm."%' AND statename='".trim($_GET['state'])."' ORDER BY city ASC");

Comment: check what are getting in `trim($_GET['state'])`

Comment: How can I check it because c_search.php file is called from Javascript function and if I print that variable on c_search.php file then it is not displaying anything. Sorry for my dumb question but I am new to JQuery.

Comment: echo variable and place die after that. And check in your browser console.

Comment: I can see something like this in console... c_search.php?state=&term=adams ... No value is passed with state variable and I guess that's why it is not giving proper result. Please let me know how can I resolve it now?

Comment: Can you please tell me how can I resolve this issue? Please reply

Comment: is `statename` is the id of your input box for state?

Comment: Yes... <input id="statename" name="statename">

Comment: I am going to home now. Will get in touch to fix this from home.

Comment: I think you are calling both of the function on load. you should call get city function on keyup.

Comment: Yes, I made necessary changes in script and it's now working fine... ty for your all help